# The changes I made on the main.storyboard do not apear in the app

Tags: swift, compilation, xcode6

I'm learning swift and IOS app development, and while doing some tests I moved some controls on the storyboard. But when I launch my app those changes do not appear, even when I do a "Clean" before to run it.
It is strange because if I add a control it appear on the app

Here is a screen shoot of the storyboard and the app runing on the IOS Simulator

http://www.designinnovation.be/documents/xcode.png

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should become familiar with [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) and introduce some constraints into your Storyboard. Then, it will arrange everything in the simulator automatically (well, for almost anything...)

Comment: I put some constraints randomly and it works, I will read the  Auto Layout  think :) Thank you

Comment: And you should look size classess too.